# pypdf2 command to convert pdf to html failing with TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes, pdfminer,

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf

I am trying to convert multiple PDF's to HTML by using the following piece of code :

```
import os
for x in range(100) :
pathName = "/Users/supreet/Downloads/PDFLocation/"
fileName = pathName + str(x+1) + ".pdf"
command = 'pdf2txt.py -o /Users/supreet/Downloads/HTMLFolder/'+str(x+1)+'.html -t html ' + fileName
os.system(command)
```

The command was working just fine a while back , but it started failing after half a day, noy sure what is happening,
Here is the error log :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/supreet/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/bin/pdf2txt.py", line 115, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "/Users/supreet/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/bin/pdf2txt.py", line 96, in main
    device = HTMLConverter(rsrcmgr, outfp, scale=scale,
  File "/Users/supreet/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pdfminer/converter.py", line 277, in __init__
    self.write_header()
  File "/Users/supreet/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pdfminer/converter.py", line 289, in write_header
    self.write('<html><head>\n')
  File "/Users/supreet/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pdfminer/converter.py", line 285, in write
    self.outfp.write(text)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

Please help me out , as it is happening with any PDF that I am trying

Comment: I dont 'use Python but due to the error you get (write() argument must be str, not bytes) I'll suggest to make a basic "print" of "command" to se what you'are really sending.

Comment: Also, the problem occurs in `pdf2txt.py`, see the backtrace, so you should paste the source of this file, not of another unrelated file.

Comment: pdf2txt.py is a utility i am using from "https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/blob/master/tools/pdf2txt.py", So i am really not sure what's happening @λuser

Comment: I printed the command @Peter :
"pdf2txt.py -o /Users/supreet/Downloads/HTMLFolder/1.html -t html /Users/supreet/Downloads/PDFLocation/1.pdf"

I can confirm these locations are correct

Comment: @supreetsingh the file you pointed to is for python2, you're running it with python3.9, so expect problems. See warning on https://github.com/euske/pdfminer: "*As of 2020, PDFMiner is not actively maintained*". Use [pdfminer.six](https://pypi.org/project/pdfminer.six/) instead which is maintained and supports python3: https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six/blob/develop/tools/pdf2txt.py

Comment: Hi @λuser, I am using pdfminer.six, I went through the documentation of it ,
The documentation mentions : 

"python pdf2txt.py samples/simple1.pdf" 

that's what I am doing as well 
I have installed pdfminer.six only